# Visual studio community 2015 Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda 4.1.1) Intellisense not working

Tags: python, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to get my IntelliSense for Python working on my Visual Studio 2015 but it just doesn't work. When I try to update the DB, it briefly starts and then stops. When I go over the refresh button by the environment name, it says the DB is not up to date, but when I go with my mouse over the "Refresh DB" below, it says the DB is up to date (Please see attached image).

[image: Image: DB not up-to-date (1) & DB up to date (2)]

I have already tried to delete the **pycache** directory in the lib directory. I have checked that the Tools > Options > Text editor > Statement Completion options were checked. I have updated the Visual studio and Python tools to the latest version today. I have been trying to find the solution online for a long time today with no luck.

I would appreciate if anyone can share a solution to this problem.

I'm also including an image of the Visual studio info if it helps at all (3) in the image.

Thank you very much.